# Hidden Cabinet files on desktop in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I just got a new computer with Windows 7.

At some point after turning on the *Show hidden files* option, I noticed that there seem to be a ton of cabinet files on my desktop. They only show up in dialog boxes (browsing to open a file or upload, etc.), but NOT on the actual desktop.

The cab files have names like `Mar2008_XAudio_x64.cab`, so they look like various program config files, but what are they doing on my desktop? Should they be there, and why do they only show up sometimes?

Answer (score 0):

No, they do not belong there. The only hidden files that should be on the desktop are 2 copies of desktop.ini, and that only if superhidden files (or supersuperhidden files) are enabled.

I'm not sure, however, where you see those files. Could you explain more fully?

Comment: So, for example, I'm doing some image editing in GIMP. If I go to Open a file and browse to the desktop in the Open window, I see the cabinet files.

Answer (score -2):

See this article:

https://www.computerworld.com/article/3112358/microsoft-windows/windows-7-log-file-compression-bug-can-fill-up-your-hard-drive.html

Seemed to work for me; had same 'symptoms'...

---

[edit]
You could simply (manually) remove just the contents of the CBS folder and the cabs themselves, which will have the same effect:

del c:\windows\logs\cbs\cbs*
del c:\windows\temp\cab*

(above from: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/495234-windows-temp-file-is-full-of-cab_xxxx-files-on-windows-server-2008-r2 )